# Separating a Person's Profile to current and on birth

Tags: single-word-requests, generic-term

I am trying to separate a person's profile into 2 groups.

1st set is the person's on birth profile:

- First Name
- Last Name
- Middle Name
- Date of Birth
- Birth Place
- Gender

2nd set is the person's current profile:

- Address 1
- Address 2
- Phone Number 1
- Phone Number 2
- Email

What would be a good term for the 1st set and the 2nd set? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st Set: Personal Details
2nd Set: Contact Details

Comment: This is one way to label them, but not the only way. Your answer would be improved with an explanation of *why* these labels are appropriate, perhaps including examples from the wild, and contrasting them with alternatives— why *details* and not *information*, for example?